# Using SUM to calculate values in multiple colums

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am using this project as a learning curve plus the the option to use it for our pool team.

I am trying to calculate how many wins/ loses and how many games played.

I have a database named weeks and in there i store quite a few columns but now needing to calculate the total number of wins and loses for all weeks i have searched around and found [this page](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/multiplying-column-values.html) which shows a nice example on how to use SUM.

My table is named weeks and it looks like this

```
id | fs1 | fs2 | fs3 | => fs12
```

I have been inserting rows for each week so for example

```
id | fs1 | fs2 | fs3 | => fs12
1     0     1     0        1           =2 wins
2     0     1     1        1           =3 wins
```

So using the code from the website i linked to above; this is my code i have at present but its not working.

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT SUM(fs1 + fs2 + fs3 + fs4 + fs5 + fs6 + fs7 + fs8 + fs9 + fs10 + fs11 + fs12) as TotalWins\n"
    . "FROM weeks";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ;
    $TotalWins =  $row['TotalWins'];

print ($TotalWins); ?>
```

This code gives me the following error `Undefined variable` and `Query was empty`

Comment: is the query working?

Comment: According the the error its a problem with line 10 Undefined variable (<?php print ($TotalWins); ?>)

Comment: if fs1,fs2... are field names then the query is wrong and i don't see any query executing code here. What error you are getting is it `Undefined variable`

Comment: yes i have added more to the question :)

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `sum()` only takes one argument and the table name goes in the `from` clause.  You can try this:

```
SELECT SUM(fs1 + fs2 + fs3 + fs4 + fs5 + fs6 + fs7 + fs8 + fs9 + fs10 + fs11) as TotalWins
FROM weeks;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am still getting Undefined variable: TotalWins

Comment: I think that is a php problem.  Can you run the query directly on the database to see if it returns what you want?  Actually, I notice that you are setting the variable `$total` but not `$TotalWins` in the php code.  Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: Your right it must be a php problem i ran your query in directly on the database and it showed me the right answer

Comment: ill delete all the code in the opening question and post the code i have currently as im still getting the same problem.

Comment: @RickNash . . . Did you change this line `$total =  $row['TotalWins']` to `$TotalWins =  $row['TotalWins']`?

Comment: @RickNash . . . Try replacing the `'\n'` with a space.  I don't think that works in SQL.

Comment: Tried and still nout, can you please check this part  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ; is this all correct?